# Files added to Visual Studio after building

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm building a solution in Visual Studio 2015 that I've just checked out. Haven't made any changes to it yet. But whenever I build for some reason over 100 files, mostly dlls, are added to my project. What is causing this? It makes it frustrating to sort through them and find the one change that I actually want to keep.

Comment: And these dlls are in the bin folders? Like bin\debug?

Comment: Yes, the dlls are under bin and the rest are under debug. The ones under debug are different file types: a build.force, some .cache and .txt and a few temp .cs files that look to be empty. Don't know what any of those are for.

Comment: You need to exclude the bin folder from source control